# App Transport Security settings for App with Watch Ext

Tags: server, plist, watchos-2

In my watch app, I need to create a urlsession. But when I want to connect to the server, xcode gave me the error

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

I tried putting the ATS settings in the "Watch Ext" plist. It's not working. I also tried putting the ATS settings in the "Container App" plist. Still same error comes out.

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue was not the location of plist file at all. It is due to how I specify the URL in the "Exception Domains".

Anyway, the location of plist to edit is in the "Watch Extension" group. If you touch the one in "Watch" group (where the storyboard is), xcode won't run your app at all. Some error will come up.

For my case, the URL I use is a bit special for eg: http://www.watch.com:90/ (at the end is specify the port). To make it work, only specify the main domain and the end part ie.

> watch.com

That is all. Then include the `NSIncludesSubdomain` key in this group.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are "temporary," for the simple reason that they will no longer be an available option to anyone who put off adopting ATS.

You need to secure your server, have your provider secure their server, or switch providers.

> You should adopt ATS as soon as possible, regardless of whether you’re creating a new app or updating an existing one. **If you’re developing a new app, you should use HTTPS exclusively.**

Apple has announced that HTTPS will be a requirement. ATS will be mandatory on Jan 1, 2017 for all Apple platforms, including watchOS.

At that point, any (new or updated) app you submit which has not adopted ATS will be rejected.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using iPhone app target os version as 9.0 and watchOS version as 2.0.

I have added below key iPhone app's info.plist and watchkit extension's info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
</dict>
```

I am successfully able to make http request from phone as well as watch.

For sample you can check
[apple watch http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246928/apple-watch-http-request/39247672#39247672)

Comment: This is a bad practice btw. You should only enable the url that your app use. If you do this, any sinister 3rd party library that u use will easily call any url as they please.

Comment: Yes, one should include NSIncludesSubdomain to work. This is to get http things working. Then you can add NSIncludesSubdomain key. Btw from 2017, iOS will block http connections anyway