# apple watch http request

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Using import, I can use this module for iPhone, but not for apple watch app.I also want to use this library for writing apple watch app. Is it possible? If possible, how? 
   Can you please provide an alternative if it is not possible?

Thanks beforehand

Simple example of http request for iPhone

```
import Alamofire
Alamofire.request(.GET, requestUrl, headers: self.headers(), encoding:.JSON).responseJSON 
{
  (rJ) -> Void in

  let data = rJ.result.value

  let err = rJ.result.error

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Sample Http request in apple watch.**

Include below key iPhone app's info.plist and watchkit extension's info.plist

```
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

In your pod file, add Alamofire to both target, i.e. iPhone and watchkit extension

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
      pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end

target 'MyApp WatchKit Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
end
```

Create your Network.swift file and add 'Target Membership' to both i.e. iPhone target and watchkit extension target.

Sample Network.swift will be,

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

struct NetworkService
{
  func executeRequest(method: Alamofire.Method,parameters:String:AnyObject]?, URLString:URLStringConvertible, completionHandler: Response<AnyObject, NSError> -> Void)
  {
    Alamofire.request(method, URLString, parameters: parameters,encoding: .JSON, headers: nil) .responseJSON { response in
        completionHandler(response)
    }
  }
}
```

Now somewhere in your code you can call this method as,

```
var sampleNWRequest:NetworkService = NetworkService()
sampleNWRequest.executeRequest(.GET, parameters: nil, URLString:"your url", completionHandler: { response in
  print(response.result.value)
 )
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: welcome !!!
But remember that apple is making mandatory to use HTTPS request. ATS will be mandatory on Jan 1, 2017 for all Apple platforms, including watchOS

Comment: To extend the above comment, Apple has rescinded their decision to mandate ATS until further notice: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12212016b